# jQuery autocomplete doesn't fire if no value was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

*Usecase: User is looking for "test"*

Working example: User writes "test" and **selects the autocomplete value**.

Issue: User writes "test" and **presses enter**!

Next time when I click in the inputfield, there is no autocomplete but it´s only when I press enter (to select the input-value) before!

```
this.$el.autocomplete({
    source: mySource,
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function(){
   that.showAutocomplete();
}).click(function(){
   that.showAutocomplete();
});

showAutocomplete: function() {
   this.$el.autocomplete("search", this.$el.val());
   console.log("was here...");
}
```

In my console there is never "was here..." so why does the autocomplete("search") event not fire?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you see any errors in console? Can you reproduce the issue in an snippet or fiddle? If you share with us a working fiddle reproducing the issue we can help you better.

Comment: Did you tried the `keypress` event?

Comment: There is no error in colsole... i'll try the keypress event and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can explain what you are precisely looking for but it seems to work here. You didn't show all your code or there are larger issues going on because the the way you are referencing `that` and defining the `showAutocomplete` function would never work as is.

But in the fiddle the autocomplete is showing on each `focus` and `click`. But it will only show results for the last search if something is selected. For example if I type `test` and `test` is not in the results nothing will show even after the field `blurs` and then I `focus` it again as long as the input is holding the value `test`. If `test` is in the results then the next time I select the field it will only show `test`. Removing the value will then show more results.

Also `that.autocomplete("search", that.val());` is not how you trigger the search event or how you initialize it. To setup the search event you would do this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        // do something on event
    }
});
```

Or after you have initialized the autocomplete you can do this:

```
$el.autocomplete("search", function (event, ui) {
        // do something on event
    }
);
```

In your example every time you you focus or click on the field you are attempting to attach a new handler for search except you just pass it a value not a function. Once search is attached, the correct way, you can manually trigger it by doing this:

```
 $el.trigger('search');
```

But to point out, this will not actually do anything in your example because you never attached a handler to the search event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/yuvdnpj7/

HTML:

```
<label for="tags">Tags:</label>
<input id="tags">
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "test",
        "Scheme"];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
    }).focus(function () {
        showAutocomplete($(this));
    }).click(function () {
        showAutocomplete($(this));
    });

    function showAutocomplete(that) {
        that.autocomplete("search", that.val());
        console.log("was here...");
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no autocomplete if i blur - set the focus out of the inputfield or delete the value...
I´ve to write a single letter and then the autocomplete works fine.

You are right, there is no "this" needed in this fiddle

Comment: You need to be a bit more verbose in what the issue is. As I explained in my answer, if you are trying to trigger the search event you first must attach a handler to it and then manually trigger it properly. What is the specific issue? The fiddle I attached has it working fine so there seems to be something wrong with your code but as I also stated in answer you have not shown all your code or have bigger issues because what you show in your question would never work.

Comment: i cant create it on jfiddle because i cant make a model there...
do you have any other idea? how could i unbind it?

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do. What do you want to unbind? What is precisely the issue you are having?